# How to update my phonegap version?

Tags: cordova

How can I update my PhoneGap version in my project?

I have download the latest version of phonegap..but how to update?

I've tried grep myAppPath .ipa 'uniqueIdentifier' *

I've gotten "access denied"

Comment: Would you mind to accept an answer?

Answer (score 67):

For Phonegap 3 installed from NPM

```
sudo npm update -g  phonegap
```

To check current version

```
phonegap -v
```

To check latest version in npm

```
npm info phonegap version
```

Comment: the same is valid for 'cordova'

Comment: Also you might need a npm update: `npm update npm -g`

Comment: Is valid for cordova too.

Answer (score 4):

Updating Cordova and Your Project

After installing the cordova utility, you can always update it to the latest version by running the following command:

```
$ sudo npm update -g cordova
```

Use this syntax to install a specific version:

```
$ sudo npm install -g cordova@3.1.0-0.2.0
```

Run cordova -v to see which version is currently running. Run the npm
info command for a longer listing that includes the current version along with other available version numbers:

```
$ npm info cordova
```

Answer (score 3):

Update phonegap version.....using terminal and run these command

```
   sudo npm update -g  phonegap
```

More Info on this link
http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/03/04/phonegap-3-4-release/

Answer (score 1):

Best option might be to create a new project in 2.7 using the getting [started guides](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20Guides) and then copy over your old project into the new project.  It is not super easy, but probably the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the instructions at: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_upgrading_index.md.html#Upgrading%20Guides

Comment: but how to upgrade from 1.2 to 2.7?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Simplest way to ensure and update latest phonegap version in your system.

1. Ensure you are using latest phonegap version. Check in github.com
   Url:https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli
   In pannel header you can able to see the version
   3.4.0-0.19.7
   latest commit c085b115ef  Lorin Beer lorinbeer authored 6 days ago
2. Check your phonegap version 
   C:\Users\user1>phonegap version
   3.4.0-0.19.6
3. Update your phonegap latest version by using 
   windows :
   C:\Users\user1>npm update -g phonegap
   Mac:
   sudo npm update -g phonegap

   ```
    or
   ```

   windows
   C:\Users\user1>npm install -g phonegap@3.4.0-0.19.7
   mac
   sudo npm install -g phonegap@3.4.0-0.19
   You can ensure you are using latest version of phonegap......

Answer (score 0):

savner has provided a good solution but in short you need to

1. install node.js
2. run the command-line interface (CLI) through node.js
       terminator
3. type Serge Seletskyy codes

good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
Mac Setup

 Step 1:Install Nodejs. You can find a tutorial here on how to setup Node.
        We will leverage Node Package Manager to setup Cordova & PhoneGap
 Step 2: Install PhoneGap – Run sudo npm install -g phonegap
 Step 3: Install Cordova Command Line tools – Run sudo npm install -g cordova
 Step 4: Install HomeBrew. We will use HomeBrew to setup Ant on our system.
 If you don’t have HomeBrew, run 
 ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
 at your terminal.
 Step 5: Install Apache-Ant. Run brew update & then install ant brew install ant
 Step 6: For iOS development, Run to the App Store & Download the latest
  version of XCode.   After the installation is completed, 
  launch the application & accept the license, terms.

iOS setup

Step 1: Create a new folder and name myApp.
Step 2: Open terminal here & Run phonegap create myFirstApp. 
This will setup the required files for a startup project.
Step 3: cd myFirstApp
Step 4: Then lets add a iOS platform instance. Run cordova platform add ios
Step 5: Build the iOS project. Run cordova build ios After a stream of messages, 
you should see something like this
```