# How to update old phonegap version to the latest one

Tags: cordova

i dowloaded the lastest ver of node.js 
but when i type phonegap --v in terminal it shows that my phonegap version is 0.9.4.

What should i do to ensure that my phonegap version is 5.1.1

Comment: You can update using this command in ios "$ sudo npm update -g cordova" and android "npm update -g cordova" . and install a specific version: "$ sudo npm install -g cordova@5.1.1".  more...http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update my phonegap version?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16591459/how-to-update-my-phonegap-version)